# Find a generator for $(f,g)$, two polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have two polynomials

$$
\def\f{x^5+2x^4+3x^3+3x^2+2x+1}
\def\g{x^5+3x^4+4x^3+4x^2+2x+1}
\def\s{\{r f + s g : r,s\in\mathbb Q[x]\}}
\def\gcd{x^2+x+1}
f=\f\\
g=\g
$$

I want find a polynomial that generates $(f,g)=\s$.

The $sf + rg$ reminded me of greatest common divisors, and it reminds me of a similar proof in group theory where we deal with elements of $\mathbb Z$ instead of elements of $\mathbb Q[x]$, and show that we have a subgroup. So I found the gcd of $f$ and $g$ using the Euclidean Algorithm, yielding:

$$
\gamma=gcd(f,g)=\gcd
$$

And I managed to show that $\s\subseteq (\gamma)$ where $(\gamma)=\{t\gamma : t\in\mathbb Q[x]\}$:

$$
a f + b g = \left(a\frac{f}\gamma + b\frac{g}\gamma\right)\gamma
$$

But I'm stuck on going the other way around. I realized that if I could put $\gcd$ in terms of $f$ and $g$, I could solve this. So now I need to find the polynomial combination of $f$ and $g$ that results in $\gamma$:

$$
c_0f + c_1g = \gcd\\\\
c_0(\f) + c_1(\g) =\gcd\\
=c_0x^5 + 2c_0 x^4 + 3c_0x^3 + 3c_0x^2 + 2c_0x + c_0
 + c_1x^5 + 3c_1x^4 + 4c_1x^3 + 4c_1x^2 + 2c_1x + c_1\\
=(c_0+c_1)x^4 + (2c_0+3c_1)x^4 + (3c_1+4c_1)x^3 + (3c_0+4c_1)x^2 + (2c_0+2c_1)x + (c_0+c_1)
$$

I don't know how to treat the $c_i$s as polynomials, so I'll pretend they're rational numbers. So I now have the system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
c_0+c_1=0\\
2c_0+3c_1=0\\
3c_0+4c_1=0\\
3c_0+4c_1=1\\
2c_0+2c_1=1\\
c_0+c_1=1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Which can't be solved because $c_0 + c_1$ can't be both $0$ and $1$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It appears the generator has to be a common factor. But if the common factor were $1$, then instead of generating just that set, we end up generating a whole lot more. So it seems that the generator can't be too small...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $c_0$ and $c_1$ can be poynomials, not just rational numbers. So, from
$$(c_0+c_1)x^5 + (2c_0+3c_1)x^4 + (3c_1+4c_1)x^3 + (3c_0+4c_1)x^2 + (2c_0+2c_1)x + (c_0+c_1)=x^2+x+1\text{,}$$
you can not obtain the system of equations you obtain, which is only valid if you assume that $c_0$ and $c_1$ are constant polynomials.

Also notice that $\exists x,y \quad xf + yg=gcd(f,g)$ by [Bézout's Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma). You don't need to know the exact value of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand how to solve it. I tried treating the polynomials as rational numbers in attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Quincunx Have you studied Euclidean algorithm in Number Theory? If so, the proccedure to solve this with polynomials, it is analogous to that which is used with polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I understand the Euclidean algorithm. That's how I found the gcd anyways. I didn't learn it in Number Theory (I haven't taken much Number Theory), I learned it in Group Theory and this current class which is introducing Galois Theory.

Comment: @Quincunx Rereead edited comment. The point is that $xa+yb=gcd(a,b)$ is resolve in the same manner for integers that for polynomials thanks to the fact that in both you have an Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @Quincunx Then this can help: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma

Comment: I thought that $\exists x,y$ such that $xa + yb = gcd(a,b)$, not $\forall x,y$

Comment: OH! That's what I needed. I just needed that $\exists x,y$ because from that I can get the containment in the other way.

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto Perhaps it would improve your original question if you added there the comments you gave here?